# How can I use cordless drill batteries in projects?

Tags: battery

I found [this project](http://blog.makezine.com/projects/make-31/fetch-o-matic/) on Make for an automatic ball thrower for your dog, and am in the process of wrapping it up.

For power, I'm using a cordless drill battery. (Specifically, a Ryobi lithium one+ 18v battery)

I've seen a lot of projects out on the web where people just use electrical tape to wrap the leads of their wire to the battery, but this seems a bit ghetto to me.

In all of the tools, the batteries "snap" into place. Is there some kind of battery mount that snaps a cordless drill battery into place and provides some leads to solder wires to? My google-fu just results in how to rebuild a cordless drill battery, which is NOT what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, what I'm looking for is this:

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:82868

I'll have to find someone with a 3D printer, but that's not too much of a problem.

Thanks everybody for their suggestions!

Comment: Your answer should contain the relevant information from the external site. Links die and the answer becomes worthless.

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to sacrifice a battery charger, you could gut the charging circuitry out of the charger housing and wire it as a battery dock.

Comment: I've done this with the dumb charger that came with my old NiCad batteries but there was basically no circuitry in it. (and it was spare since I replaced it with a smart charger)

Comment: The case of a broken-down power tool for these batteries will also do. Such broken tools are often sold for a few bucks on eBay etc. "for parts".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I found this here. Keystone BK-204 battery clips that slide right on, and then all you have to do is attach a wire.

[Ryobi Battery Cap](http://www.shapeways.com/product/AKLLTR6WK/ryobi-battery-cap?optionId=36617339)